# Rest endpoint and sample json request to call rules deployed in jBPM?

Tags: rest, drools, jbpm, redhat-brms, redhat-bpm

I created sample rule project through KIE workbench 6.3.0 and deployed it successfully through the console.
This endpoint gives me the deployment details succeesfully -> `http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/deployment/com.mycompany.myprojects:itz376-project:1.0.0.0`

```
{
    "groupId": "com.mycompany.myprojects",
    "artifactId": "itz376-project",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "kbaseName": "",
    "ksessionName": "",
    "strategy": "SINGLETON",
    "status": "DEPLOYED"
}
```

Could somebody help me with the endpoint and sample json payload to invoke the rules using REST api?
All available documentation talks about starting process/tasks etc.
How can I invoke the rules directly?

Comment: I have been posting to the following url, but it always gives 404 :  
http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/runtime/com.mycompany.myprojects:itz376-project:1.0.0.0/execute

Comment: jbpm-console is all about JBPM (business processes). If you want to deploy and execute a Drools based solution, then you should be using the `kie-server` application, or create your own solution.

Comment: you are right @EstebanAliverti

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint I am using is not supported anymore, it was removed in BRMS/BPM Suite 6.

To execute rules you must configure the Decision Server as described in [1] and then generate and send requests to it as described in [2].

```
[1] https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2106041
[2] https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1486613
```